# How do I permanently add to $PATH for all users?

Tags: path

I made a directory `/opt`. How can I add it to the path for all users?

I tried adding it to `/etc/profile` but it didn't work.

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt"
fi
export PATH
```

Comment: Are the binaries directly in /opt, or a subdirectory of it?

Comment: of course, there's a minor possibility that a user overrides the whole `PATH` in their personal shell startup files

Comment: @JeffSchaller, the binaries are directly in `/opt`.
@ilkkachu, that is not the case here. If a user does that, they deserve to have everything not work.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you have the user log out and back in after making that change?

Comment: Are you sure your users are using bourne shell or its compatible versions? If they are using `zsh` or `csh` for example, they may not use `/etc/profile`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, until all of the kinks are worked out, I will be the only user.

Comment: @AndyDalton, I rebooted the machine.

Comment: Putting it into `/etc/profile` should work. If it doesn't then I guess you should be able to debug it by putting a `echo PATH=$PATH` at the beginning and at the end of all the shell config files (`/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc`, etc.). Note that you did not mention which shell you are using.